# Executar function quando o elemento surgir no dom

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como executar uma `function` quando um determinado elemento existir no `DOM`?

Por exemplo, tenho uma lista com 4 elementos, e sempre que surgir um novo elemento eu quero que seja executado uma determinada `function`. Código de exemplo abaixo:

```js
// Função a ser executada
function fazAlgoNaLI() {
  $(this).addClass('alterada');
}

// Execução quando os elementos já existem no dom
$('li').each(fazAlgoNaLI);

// Agora vamos adicionando elementos após e preciso executar a funcion quando esse elemento for adicionado
setInterval(function() {
  $('ul').append('<li>Nova linha</li>');
}, 1000);
```

```css
.alterada {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Linha 1</li>
  <li>Linha 2</li>
  <li>Linha 3</li>
</ul>
```

> OBS1: Uma premissa é que eu não tenho como controlar o momento que esse
>   elemento é alterado pois são vários JavaScripts de terceiro que estão
>   todos minificados. Então preciso de um evento que execute a function quando o DOM for alterado.

---

> OBS2: Eu consegui com um setInterval rodando por exemplo a cada 100 milisegundos, verificar e executar a função, mas queria uma solução mais performática que não ficasse rodando uma função o tempo todo na aplicação.

Comment: [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). E [pergunta relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50616).

Comment: O problema do MutationObserver é que a implementação nos browsers ainda não é confiável...

Comment: Até hoje? Essa especificação já tem uns bons anos. A tabela de compatibilidade que tem na MDN parece ok.

Comment: @bfavaretto eu ia comentar, somente o Safari 6 e 7 que necessitam do prefixo. Os demais navegadores considerados modernos (em "dia") funcionam perfeitamente :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sugiro que use uma destas 3 maneiras de verificar:

### Setando uma propriedade no elemento

Antes de tudo recomendo que leia isto:

- [Por que dizem que recursividade de setTimeout é melhor que setInterval?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77764/3635)

Então, se a estrutura é de fato simples da maneira que fez, e os elementos são sempre LIs então um `setTimeout` que checaria os que já tem a propriedade ou não:

```js
// Função a ser executada
function fazAlgoNaLI() {
    if (this.alterado) return; //Ignora se já tiver a propriedade

    this.alterado = true;
    
    $(this).addClass('alterada');
}

// Agora vamos adicionando elementos após e preciso executar a funcion quando esse elemento for adicionado
setInterval(function() {
  $('.foo').append('<li>Nova linha</li>');
}, 1000);

/* verifica alterações*/
var quantidade = 0;
(function mutacao() {
    var lis = $('.foo > li');

    //verifica se a quantidade aumentou
    if (quantidade !== lis.length) {
        lis.each(fazAlgoNaLI);
        quantidade = lis.length; //Atualiza a ultima quantidade
    }
    
    setTimeout(mutacao, 100);
})();
```

```css
.alterada {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="foo">
  <li>Linha 1</li>
  <li>Linha 2</li>
  <li>Linha 3</li>
</ul>
```

### Usando o seletor `:not(...)`

Ou então pode pegar apenas os que não tiverem a classe `class="alterada"`, para isto use o seletor `:not(...)`, faça assim:

```js
// Função a ser executada
function fazAlgoNaLI() {
    $(this).addClass('alterada');
}

// Agora vamos adicionando elementos após e preciso executar a funcion quando esse elemento for adicionado
setInterval(function() {
  $('.foo').append('<li>Nova linha</li>');
}, 1000);

(function mutacao() {
    var lis = $('.foo > li:not(.alterada)'); //Pega somente elementos que não tiverem a classe alterada

    lis.each(fazAlgoNaLI);
    
    setTimeout(mutacao, 100);
})();
```

```css
.alterada {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="foo">
  <li>Linha 1</li>
  <li>Linha 2</li>
  <li>Linha 3</li>
</ul>
```

### Usando MutationObserver

Você pode usar a `MutationObserver` que verifica com combinado com `addedNodes`, somente os novos elementos adicionados e então você pode combinar com `.filter`, do jQuery, para verificar se é uma tag válida, ou no caso verificar se foi um LI adicionado:

```js
// Função a ser executada
function fazAlgoNaLI() {
    $(this).addClass('alterada');
}

// Agora vamos adicionando elementos após e preciso executar a funcion quando esse elemento for adicionado
setInterval(function() {
    $('.foo').append('<li>Nova linha</li>');
}, 1000);

/* verifica alterações*/
var isReady = 0;

var observer = new MutationObserver(function( mutations ) {
  mutations.forEach(function( mutation ) {
    var nn = mutation.addedNodes;

    if (nn !== null) {

        console.log("Foi adicionado " + nn.length + " novo elemento");

        $(nn).filter('li').each(fazAlgoNaLI);
    }
  });    
});

var config = { 
    childList: true
};

//Inicia o observador
observer.observe($(".foo").get(0), config);
```

```css
.alterada {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="foo">
  <li>Linha 1</li>
  <li>Linha 2</li>
  <li>Linha 3</li>
</ul>
```